# Can a command be executed without a shell?

Tags: shell, ssh, command

I am developing a binary executable program command to execute programs and return the output into a text field.

The parameters to the command involve the command itself as it would be typed on the command line, and the directory. So the routine that executes the operation first switches to the directory, then executes the command.

For example if I want to execute the command `some.cmd` in the directory `/home/user` the parameters are `command = 'some.cmd'` and `directory = '/home/user'`.

What I have found is that `some.cmd` does not work but if I change command to `/home/user/some.cmd` the command works. However the command `ls -l` works. I also notice that the `cd` command is not recognized. If I run it remotely via `ssh` such as setting command to `ssh user@localhost 'cd /home/user && ./some.cmd'` it works.

It seems that some settings which are present when the command is executed in a shell are not present when it is run directly, but doing it via `ssh` seems to create the settings for it work.

Is there some explanation for this?

**UPDATE:**
After some enquiries I got to learn that the API used for executing the commands were not being executed in the shell, or were not executed with the normal environment available from the console. After executing the commands with the `/bin/sh -c "cd ..."` option the problem is no more. This is the environment doing `ssh user@localhost 'command ...'` gave me.I am not so sure of the technical details, but apparently the existence of the environment available when you execute in your normal shell is not always available to commands executed directly by the OS.

Comment: Do you really need to `cd` before running your command? Why not just `ssh user@localhost /home/user/some.cmd`?

Comment: You never explained how you implemented the `directory ` parameter.

Comment: @roaima Preceding the command with  'ssh user@localhost' is an unnecessary overhead and there should be a way of creating the environment without logging in again via SSH

Comment: The API I am using has a property called 'CurrentDirectory' and it switches to the 'CurrentDirectory' before executing 'Command'. It is not actually a shell, like bash. As I said 'ls -l' returns the correct output so 'Current Directory' is set properly.

Comment: @vfclists when I try to resolve a question I like to partition the problem. You yourself offered `ssh user@localhost` so I started with that as a working assumption and asked whether you really needed the `cd` for your application to work. Once I had the answer to that I would have been able to make a decision how to proceed with an offered solution.

Comment: @roaima I used the `ssh@localhost `method to test if it the problem was related to creation of the environment which turned out to be the case, but `ssh@localhost` incurs  an overhead and it requires extra care with escaping strings which is why is not appropriate for my usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you try to execute a file, the system has to know how to find the file.  That's why it works if you specify the full path to it.  The shell also has a `PATH` environment variable that stores a list of directories to look in to find an executable.  That's why you don't have to specify the full path for `ls`.

Comment: Why then does the 'cd` command not work?

Comment: @vfclists ; Because `cd` is a shell builtin command not found via `PATH`. (If you need a C library function have a look at `chdir()`.)

Comment: Do you mean that `cd` depends on the shell but `ls` does not? The problem is that if the `ls` command can list the directory contents correctly then why can't the executable which is already there not run?

Comment: Right, `cd` is a command the shell knows how to implement `ls` is an external executable (often `/bin/ls`, you can find yours by doing `which ls`).  The `PATH` variable tells the shell to look in `/bin` among other places, so when you try to run `ls` it find the executable and runs it.  Generally `.` is not in `PATH` so just being in the same directory as an executable does not make it "findable" to run, that's why using `./some.cmd` works, you are now telling it where to find it instead of making it look in `PATH`

Comment: @vfclists you may be interested in the `type` command too, which will give you information about what will happen if you try to run a command.  For example `type cd` gives me `cd is a shell builtin` and `type ls` gives me `ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'` and can be augmented with `which ls` which gives me `alias ls='ls --color=auto'
        /bin/ls`

Answer (score 4):

This is entirely an issue with the command not being in your `PATH`. Unlike Windows systems the current directory is not implicitly in the search path for executables. To run a command such as `ls` (eg `ls -l`) it needs to be in your `PATH`, and indeed it is - `type ls` will show you it's either in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. However, `some.cmd` is not in your `PATH` and so cannot be executed transparently as a command. Three options spring to mind:

1. You can move `some.cmd` to a directory that is in your `PATH`. For example, on some distributions `/usr/local/bin/` and `"$HOME"/bin` are added to the `PATH` by default
2. You can add `"$HOME"` to your `PATH`
3. You can run `./some.cmd` (a relative path to the current directory) instead of trying to use plain `some.cmd`

Comment: I think you may have misread the question. The commands are not entered into a terminal, but are executed by an application. `ssh@localhost` works as I expect because the commands get run in a terminal environment. What I need is for the application to be able to execute the commands as though they are typed in a terminal without going through SSH and return the output, a command that creates the environment like `ssh@localhost` does, but a local one.

Comment: @vfclists yes, exactly. The PATH needs to be set, or you need to provide /some/sort/of/path to the application you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi**

---

### First Way :

You Can Use The `Libeshell  C++ Library` For Writing Shell-like Console Applications

with This Library You Can  Creation Of Command-line And Shell-style Applications

---

### Second Way :

Use The This Code For Execute The Command With C++ :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

system("gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'mkdir /root/Desktop/New-Dir-1 ; mkdir /root/New-Dir-2'");
}
```